# How to pass AngularJS variable value to C# controller?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to get angularjs value from AngularController.js to CCharpController.cs

This I want to sum value from $scope.count1 and $scope.count2

`

```
$scope.onSubmit = function () {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < $scope.Data.length ; i++) {
        if ($scope.Data[i].1 === true) {
            $scope.count1 += 1;
        }
        else if ($scope.Data[i].2 === true) {
            $scope.count2 += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

`

and pass to CCharp function like this,

`

```
[Route("api/WarehousePlan/AllowWarehousePlan")]
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public IHttpActionResult AllowWarehousePlan([FromBody] WarehouseAllowDenyModel model){ 
    ....
    var count = $scope.count1 + $scope.count2 }
```

`

I expect receive count value from angularjs function.

Comment: you need to use a service that is calling your api endpoint  look here: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/processing-forms-in-angularjs

Comment: You might have to make `HttpPost` request to API URL with the count value as a parameter, then your C# controller will receive it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

First declare a model

```
$scope.modelVM = {};
```

Then assign the parameter into model as likes you declare in your model class

```
 $scope.modelVM.count1 += 1;
 $scope.modelVM.count2 += 1;
```

After then post the model via http

```
 $http.post('api/WarehousePlan/AllowWarehousePlan', $scope.modelVM).then(
            function (successResponse) {
                if (successResponse.status == '200') {
                    alert("Data Submit Successfully..");
                }
            },
            function (errorResponse) {
                alert("Not Successful");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set value in Cookie in Controller file,

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["count1"].Value = "1";
```

You can access cookie value in JS file,

```
$scope.count1 = $cookies.get("count1");
```

To Update Cookie value in JS file,

```
$cookies.put('count1',2);
```